# Setup validation messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm using config file for the validation rules. The problem is that I can't figure out how to set a custom message for each field in the config file. Here is my config

```
$config = array(
   'user/signup' => array(
                      array(
                              'field' => 'email',
                              'label' => 'Email',
                              'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
                           ),
                      array(
                              'field' => 'password',
                              'label' => 'Password',
                              'rules' => 'required|matches[confirm_password]|min_length[5]|max_length[12]'
                           ),
....
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the native error messages are located in the following language file: language/english/form_validation_lang.php

To set your own custom message you can either edit that file, or use the following function:

`$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be done.

How about extending the form validation library and including the error messages in the set_rules function?